# Power BI how to gets numbers from forecast

Tags: powerbi

In power BI you can insert a Line Chart Visual and you can choose to forecast a single line.
What I want is to get all the forecasted values (Forecast 1) from the forecast part. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: You can use forecast package in R and R script in PBI to get the results.